# Pytorch CNN Loss is not changing

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I am making a CNN using Pytorch for an image classification problem between people who are wearing face masks and who aren't. The images are converted to a 256x256 with 3 channels.

When the code is run, whatever the initial loss value is will stay the same. I have tried changing the learning rates, however there is no change. I have also tried using a simple single linear layer to check if it was the model that was incorrect. My guess is that the training loop is incorrect, but when comparing to other sample training loops, my code looks correct.

**Model**

```py
class NetConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NetConv, self).__init__()
        # self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        # self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        # self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels= 3, out_channels = 8, kernel_size = 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels= 8, out_channels = 16, kernel_size = 3)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels= 16, out_channels = 32, kernel_size = 3)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(30*30*32, 1000)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1000, 200)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(200, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
        # print(x.shape)
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)

        x = x.reshape(-1, 30*30*32)

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)

        # print(x.shape)
 
        return x
```

**Dataloader**

```py
class faceMaskDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, img_folder, annot_folder, transform=None):
        # Extracting image name and class from xml file
        desc = []
        for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk(annot_folder):
            for filename in filenames:
                desc.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

        img_name,label = [],[]

        for d in desc:
            content = []
            n = []

            with open(d, "r") as file:
                content = file.readlines()
            content = "".join(content)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
            file_name = soup.filename.string
            name_tags = soup.find_all("name")
            
            for t in name_tags:
                n.append(t.get_text())
                
            # selecting tag with maximum occurence in an image (If it has multiple tags)
            name = max(set(n), key = n.count)
        
            img_name.append(file_name)
            label.append(name)

        labels = pd.get_dummies(label)
        print(labels.head())

        # Our target classes
        classes = list(labels.columns)
        print(classes)

        data, target = [],[]
        img_h, img_w = 256, 256

        # Loading images and converting them to pixel array
        for i in range(len(img_name)):
            name = os.path.join("./images/1", img_name[i])
            image = cv2.imread(name)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image = cv2.resize(image, (img_w, img_h), cv2.INTER_AREA)
            
            data.append(image)
            target.append(tuple(labels.iloc[i,:]))

        print(type(data))
        # data = np.array(data)
        data = np.array(data) / 255 # Normalise pixel data to between 0 and 1
        target = np.array(target)
        
        data = np.swapaxes(data, 1, 3)
        data = np.swapaxes(data, 2, 3)

        self.data = data
        
        self.target = target
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.target)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image = self.data[index,:]
        label = (self.target[index])
        return (image, label)
```

**Training loop**

```py
def train(model, optimizer, loss_fn, train_dl, val_dl, epochs=20, device='cuda'):

    for epoch in range(epochs):

        model.train()
        train_loss         = 0.0
        num_train_correct  = 0
        num_train_examples = 0

        for i, (image, target) in enumerate(train_dl):
            image = image.to(device).float()
            target = target.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            output = model(image)

            loss = loss_fn(output, torch.max(target, 1)[1]) 

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            train_loss         += loss.data.item() * image.size(0)
            num_train_correct  += (torch.max(output, 1)[1] == torch.max(target, 1)[1]).sum().item()

            num_train_examples += image.shape[0]

        train_acc   = num_train_correct / num_train_examples
        train_loss  = train_loss / len(train_dl.dataset)
        print("Epoch: %2d, Loss: %.3f, Acc: %.3f" % (epoch, train_loss, train_acc))
```

Comment: What loss function do you use for `loss_fn`?

Comment: If you're using `categorical cross-entropy` as your loss function, then you need to remove the `softmax` from the forward pass, as `categorical cross-entropy` itself calculates the `softmax` for you.

Comment: @KhalidSaifullah, it includes a `nn.LogSoftmax` to be more correct.

Comment: @Ivan I am using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` for my `loss_fn`. Removing the `softmax` still yields the same result.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you are calling `train` (with `model`'s and `optimizer`'s init)